# Are there any Christian groups that believe in only One God (The Father revealed by Christ) and only One Gospel rather than 4 Gospels?

Tags: christology, denomination-survey, gospels, monotheism

In which Christian group is Oneness strong (One God revealed by One Christ revealed in One Gospel in One language)?

Comment: I do not understand the "one Gospel" idea.  Gospel is used in two sense - the good news of salvation, and, the gospel records of the four evangelists of Matthew, Mark, Luke & John.  Which of these do you mean?  The Bible is written in three different languages, Hebrew, Aramaic and Greek.

Comment: I mean only One True Written Gospel

Comment: Then do you mean a single one of the existing Gospels?  Or, an amalgam of the four?

Comment: Only One, even if it's a single harmony gospel.

Answer (score 2):

The following groups believe in only one God and so are stridently anti-trinitarian and not even Arian nor Binitarian.  This is NOT an exhaustive list but tries to include the numerically largest groups.  Others may be able to add more.

- Unitarians
- Unitarian Universalists
- Jehovah's Witnesses
- Judaism
- Christadelphians
- Monarchianism

Comment: Judaism is not a Christian group.

Comment: True - but I included it for completeness.

Comment: I don't know any of these that only accept one written gospel.

Comment: Correct - I do not know of any who believe one single written gospel either.